# Beanstalkd queue process per user

Tags: php, architecture, worker, beanstalkd, job-queue

I'm having an application with a couple thousand users. Each user can have 10 - 100's of jobs in the queue. I wan't my workers (~10) to process 10 jobs of 10 different users instead of just 10 jobs (which could be from the same user).

```
user1
    job1
    job2
    job3
    job4
    job5
user2
    job6
    job7
    job8
user3
    job9
    job10
    ...
```

So in the above example I want my workers to process in the following order:

```
worker1 -> job1, job2, job3
worker2 -> job6, ...
worker3 -> job9, ...
...
```

Is there any way this is easy to implement with beanstalkd (prefered) or gearman?

Comment: Could you be more precise about your constraint ? If you know how to do to execute 10 jobs for 1 user, why did you blocked when you want to execute 10 jobs for 10 user ?

Comment: I've changed my original post so it's a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you can use [tube](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/faq#what-are-tubes-and-how-do-they-work) feature.

you can have

- tube for each user(user1, user2, user3,...)
- controller tube

then step will be like this

#### job producer:

1. add job to user's tube.
2. add tube's name that you just inserted to controller tube.

#### job worker:

1. reserve(with no timeout) to controller tube
2. got job from controller tube
3. loop reserve-with-timeout(with timeout = 0) to user's tube until you got TIMED_OUT
4. start again with 1.

> **reverse** This will return a newly-reserved job. If no job is available to be reserved,
>   beanstalkd will wait to send a response until one becomes available.
>
> **reverse-with-timeout**
>   A timeout value of 0 will cause the server to immediately return either a
>   response or TIMED_OUT.  A positive value of timeout will limit the amount of
>   time the client will block on the reserve request until a job becomes
>   available.

[reference docs](https://raw.github.com/kr/beanstalkd/master/doc/protocol.txt)

Comment: This way I would get easily a couple thousand tubes as the user amount could be from 500 up to over 10k!